# Why does even wait() gets called when the thread has not passed inside synchronised

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a basic doubt.
Wait is called inside Synchronized block, But when there are 2 threads are accessing the blocks locked by synchronized, I thought when one thread has already gone into the synchronized, The other thread cannot enter the block?  But i see that it goes and once wait() is executed other thread enters the critical section.  so 2 threads inside the critical section where as one thread, waiting at the wait() call. Is  this really the way it works ? All these years I was thinking there could be only 1 thread at once inside the synchronized block.

Please help me understanding it.......... your help. I have seen various links, Your personal words explaining me its working in just a paragraph, is a lot to me.

Thankyou

Comment: You should read the javadoc for the wait() method.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the javadoc for the wait method explains everything you need to know...

Answer (score 1):

Calling wait() suspends the executing thread and releases the lock held by synchronize. When the wait() is ended by a call to notify() or notifyAll(), the lock is reacquired before the return from the wait().

Answer (score 1):

When `wait` is called on an object the lock on the object is automatically released to allow other threads to make progress. For example:

```
synchronized(obj) {
    obj.wait();
}
```

When a thread acquires the lock on `obj` and then calls `obj.wait()` the thread is suspended and the lock on object `obj` is released to allow another thread to call `obj.notify()` for example.

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) says it pretty clearly:

> The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread releases
>   ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies
>   threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a
>   call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then
>   waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes
>   execution.